# Can't run MonoTouch App

Tags: iphone, project, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

This is not a really Programming Question, but please bear with me as it's related to the IDE that we use to develop and I'm really Stuck! :(

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-06_0926.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-06_0926.png)

Every time I create a project (can be an empty project) I get the message above when pressing Run or Debug.

I have **no Web Servers running** the Web Share is off, the Zend Server as well MAMP is Off, the app itself **does nothing as it's a blank project** and if I run it on the iPhone/iPad Simulator, the app just **opens and closes automatically** :-/

I'm all **new to monoTouch**, but I wonder, does anyone has this problem and know what should I do?

- Running OSX 10.6.3
- iPhone SDK 3.2
- MonoDevelop 2.2.2
- MonoTouch Eval 2.0.1

Thank you for all the help.

---

Answer back to Steven's question

```
mac-bruno:~ balexandre$ lsof -i | grep LISTEN
AppleVNCS  536 balexandre    8u  IPv6 0x075cd460      0t0  TCP *:vnc-server (LISTEN)
Dropbox    577 balexandre   18u  IPv4 0x09f86b1c      0t0  TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox    577 balexandre   20u  IPv4 0x09f846b0      0t0  TCP practivate.adobe.com:26164 (LISTEN)
synergys   592 balexandre    5u  IPv4 0x075ce274      0t0  TCP *:24800 (LISTEN)
JavaAppli  815 balexandre   33u  IPv6 0x0f8b3bb0      0t0  TCP [::127.0.0.1]:6880 (LISTEN)
JavaAppli  815 balexandre   45u  IPv6 0x075cc350      0t0  TCP *:39582 (LISTEN)
JavaAppli  815 balexandre   48u  IPv6 0x0f8b3460      0t0  TCP *:41688 (LISTEN)
JavaAppli  815 balexandre   51u  IPv6 0x0f8b3940      0t0  TCP [::127.0.0.1]:45100 (LISTEN)
JavaAppli  815 balexandre  108u  IPv6 0x0f911d10      0t0  TCP *:58573 (LISTEN)
mac-bruno:~ balexandre$
```

Comment: What happens if you navigate to "localhost" on your computer? Doesn't any server respond?

Comment: No servers running :) "Safari can’t open the page “http://localhost/” because Safari can’t connect to the server “localhost”.", even in ports that I use most, 4567 (Sinatra), 10081 (Zend), 8080 (Mamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is obviously listening on the port, I *think* it uses 10000 by default, although my Mac isn't on to check. If you fire up a terminal and run:

> lsof -i | grep LISTEN

It should show you all processes that are listening for connections, hopefully that will point you in the right direction as to what's causing the conflict.

Edit: From the [MonoTouch Troubleshooting page](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Troubleshoot#Debugger_is_unable_to_connect_with_the_device)

> Debugger is unable to connect with the
>   device
>
> When you start debugging a device
>   configuration, you will see the
>   debugger show a dialog indicating that
>   it is listening on a particular IP
>   address. This IP address is also built
>   into the application as a default
>   setting. When you start the
>   application in debug mode, it makes a
>   connection to MonoDevelop, the
>   debugger host. If it is unable to
>   connect, the device will vibrate once.
>
> There are several reasons the
>   application may not be able to connect
>   to the debugger:
>
> If the device and the debugger host
>   are on different networks, a firewall
>   or private network may be preventing
>   the application from connecting to the
>   debugger host.
>
> MonoDevelop may picked the wrong host
>   IP address. MonoDevelop picks the
>   first IP address on the machine,
>   which, if you have multiple network
>   interfaces, may not be the one you
>   want. You can override the IP that
>   MonoDevelop uses by quitting
>   MonoDevelop and editing its settings
>   file. This is in a hidden directory in
>   in your home directory,
>   ~/.config/MonoDevelop/MonoDevelopProperties.xml.
>
> Look for the key
>   "MonoTouch.Debugger.HostIP", and edit
>   the value. If it is not present you
>   will need to add it:
>
> view plainprint?    where w.x.y.z is
>   the IP you wish to use.
>
> The debugger host's IP address may
>   have changed. MonoDevelop has to embed
>   the host's IP address in the
>   application's default settings so that
>   it knows what address to connect to.
>   If the host's IP changes after you
>   build the app, you need to rebuild and
>   re-upload the app, or change the IP
>   address entry in the app's settings on
>   the device.

Comment: from this post (http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Nov-04.html) it shows that 10000 is used to Debug, as well 10001, but I have nothing pointed to that port :-( ...Searching a place to change that port!

Comment: I've asked on the monotouch irc channel but nobody is really awake yet. I can't see any option to change it in MonoDevelop, but you can change it on the iPhone/sim itself so it must be possible to change it on the development machine too.

Comment: Just another thought.. you don't have any software firewall or something like LittleSnitch running do you?

Comment: I think that troubleshooting is for debugging on the iPhone Device, not the Simulator, right? And no, no Firewall, no AntiVirus installed :)

Comment: I think it works the same way for both, they both sit and wait for connections on that port.